# I can’t find the problem with my PyQt5 project

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am currently writing my first project (game) in PyQt 5. The problem is that when the user goes from selecting the mode to the game itself, it freezes (that is, it starts loading endlessly). It's not the first week I've been trying to fix the problem, but it doesn't work. Please help me!

This is my code:

```
import datetime as dt
import sys
from random import randrange
from typing import List, Callable

from PyQt5 import uic, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLabel, QStackedWidget, QApplication


class Board(QMainWindow):  # the first form - the main window of the game
    time_interval: dt.timedelta
    have_time: dt.timedelta
    date: dt.date
    timer: QtCore.QTimer
    now_game_mode: int
    questions: int
    pixmap: QPixmap
    image: QLabel
    now_subject: str
    score_number: int
    subject_number: int
    data: List[str]
    start_time: dt.datetime
    end_time: dt.datetime
    str_end_time: str
    str_start_time: str
    i: int
    duration: dt.timedelta
    stackedWidget: QStackedWidget
   
    what_is = ‘What is on the map with number’
    congratulations = ‘Congratulations!’
    time_interval = dt.timedelta(seconds=60)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        self.score_number = 0
        self.subject_number = 0
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.now_subject = ''
        self.have_time = dt.timedelta(milliseconds=self.timer.interval())
        self.date = dt.date.today()

    def initUI(self):
        uic.loadUi("design.ui", self)
        self.setGeometry(400, 400, 800, 800)
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.send_mode_choice.clicked.connect(self.set_game_mode)
        self.send_rus.clicked.connect(self.send)
        self.idk_1.clicked.connect(self.idk)

    def set_game_mode(self):  # game mode selection
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)
        self.start_time = dt.datetime.now()  # start time of a new game
        if self.russian_subjects.isChecked():
            self.questions = 23
            f = open('subjects.txt', mode='rt', encoding='UTF-8')  # file with exercises
            self.data = f.read().split("\n")
            self.game()

    def game(self):  # the game process
        ask: bool
        ask = True

        def ready():
            nonlocal ask
            ask = True

        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)
        self.timer.setInterval(self.time_interval // dt.timedelta(milliseconds=1))  # setting the duration of the game
        self.have_time = self.time_interval
        self.timer.start()
        self.i = 0  # number of question asked
        while self.have_time > dt.timedelta() and self.i <= self.questions:
            ask = False
            print(self.i)
            print(self.have_time)
            self.i += 1
            self.time_1.setText(str(self.have_time.seconds))
            self.subject_number = randrange(1, 24)  # choosing the exercise
            self.now_subject = self.data[self.subject_number - 1].split(';')[1]
            print(self.now_subject)
            self.ex_1.setText(f"{self.what_is}{self.subject_number}?")  # вывод задания
            self.have_time = dt.timedelta(milliseconds=self.timer.remainingTime())
            while not ask:
                pass
        # after the game's end
        # ...

    def send(self, ready: Callable[[], None]):
        print(repr(self.answer_1.text().lower()))
        print(repr(self.now_subject))
        print(repr(self.answer_1.text().lower() == self.now_subject))
        # checking the correctness of the answer
        if self.answer_1.text().lower() == self.now_subject:
            self.score_number += 1
            self.score_lcd.display(self.score_number)
            self.wrong_answer.setText('')
        else:
            # until the answer is correct or until the game time ends there will be no transition to the next question
            while self.answer_1.text().lower() != self.now_subject and self.have_time > dt.timedelta(milliseconds=0):
                self.have_time = dt.timedelta(milliseconds=self.timer.interval())
                self.wrong_answer.setText('К сожалению, ответ неверный')
            ready()

    def idk(self, ready: Callable[[], None]):
        self.answer_1.setText(self.now_subject)
        self.wrong_answer.setText('Look at the correct answer')
        self.subject_number = randrange(1, 24)
        self.now_subject = self.data[self.subject_number - 1].split(';')[1]
        # timer for 2 seconds so that the user looks at the correct answer (after the end, the next question is asked)
        timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        timer.setSingleShot(True)
        timer.timeout.connect(ready)
        timer.start(2_000)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Board()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

design.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1366</width>
    <height>644</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <property name="animated">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
    <property name="leftMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="topMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="rightMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="bottomMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <item>
     <widget class="QStackedWidget" name="stackedWidget">
      <property name="currentIndex">
       <number>6</number>
      </property>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="page">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="mode_choice">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>340</x>
          <y>150</y>
          <width>151</width>
          <height>31</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Что будем отгадывать?</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QWidget" name="verticalLayoutWidget">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>330</x>
          <y>200</y>
          <width>160</width>
          <height>80</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
         <item>
          <widget class="QRadioButton" name="russian_subjects">
           <property name="text">
            <string>Субъекты РФ</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QRadioButton" name="europe_countries">
           <property name="text">
            <string>Страны Европы</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="send_mode_choice">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>390</x>
          <y>300</y>
          <width>113</width>
          <height>32</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Отправить</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="score_label">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>1070</x>
          <y>30</y>
          <width>59</width>
          <height>16</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string/>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="page_2">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="score">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>80</x>
          <y>10</y>
          <width>59</width>
          <height>16</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>очки:</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="idk_1">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>600</x>
          <y>590</y>
          <width>113</width>
          <height>32</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Не знаю</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QLineEdit" name="answer_1">
        <property name="enabled">
         <bool>true</bool>
        </property>
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>560</x>
          <y>550</y>
          <width>291</width>
          <height>31</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="send_rus">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>710</x>
          <y>590</y>
          <width>113</width>
          <height>32</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Отправить</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QLCDNumber" name="score_lcd">
        <property name="enabled">
         <bool>false</bool>
        </property>
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>130</x>
          <y>10</y>
          <width>64</width>
          <height>23</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="image">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>20</x>
          <y>50</y>
          <width>1281</width>
          <height>471</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string/>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="show_mode">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>600</x>
          <y>10</y>
          <width>191</width>
          <height>20</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Режим 1: Субъекты РФ</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="wrong_answer">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>320</x>
          <y>540</y>
          <width>451</width>
          <height>20</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string/>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="ex_1">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>560</x>
          <y>530</y>
          <width>281</width>
          <height>20</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string/>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="time_1">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>1160</x>
          <y>20</y>
          <width>171</width>
          <height>16</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string/>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="have_seconds">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>1040</x>
          <y>0</y>
          <width>131</width>
          <height>51</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Осталось секунд:</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="page_3">
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="idk_2">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>520</x>
          <y>500</y>
          <width>113</width>
          <height>32</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Не знаю</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="send_rus_2">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>630</x>
          <y>500</y>
          <width>113</width>
          <height>32</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Отправить</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QLineEdit" name="answer_2">
        <property name="enabled">
         <bool>true</bool>
        </property>
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>440</x>
          <y>450</y>
          <width>291</width>
          <height>31</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="score2">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>180</x>
          <y>120</y>
          <width>59</width>
          <height>16</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>очки:</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QLCDNumber" name="score_lcd_2">
        <property name="enabled">
         <bool>false</bool>
        </property>
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>220</x>
          <y>120</y>
          <width>64</width>
          <height>23</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="show_mode_eur">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>370</x>
          <y>20</y>
          <width>201</width>
          <height>16</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Режим 2: Страны Европы</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="page_4">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>540</x>
          <y>30</y>
          <width>441</width>
          <height>61</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Поздравляю!</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QWidget" name="verticalLayoutWidget_2">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>320</x>
          <y>130</y>
          <width>561</width>
          <height>231</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
         <item>
          <widget class="QPushButton" name="statistic">
           <property name="text">
            <string>посмотреть статистику игры</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QPushButton" name="send_comment">
           <property name="text">
            <string>оставить комментарий</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QPushButton" name="start_new_game">
           <property name="text">
            <string>начать новую игру</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </widget>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="page_5">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>360</x>
          <y>40</y>
          <width>741</width>
          <height>141</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Вы можете посмотреть статистику по своим игровым попыткам или по самым сложным для Вас заданиям</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="tries_statistic">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>510</x>
          <y>190</y>
          <width>321</width>
          <height>41</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Статистика по попыткам</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="exercises_statistic">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>510</x>
          <y>270</y>
          <width>321</width>
          <height>41</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Статистика по заданиям</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="page_6">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_4">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>520</x>
          <y>20</y>
          <width>441</width>
          <height>31</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>В этой таблице находится статистика по всем Вашим попыткам</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QTableWidget" name="tableWidget">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>290</x>
          <y>80</y>
          <width>901</width>
          <height>551</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="show_1">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>90</x>
          <y>120</y>
          <width>113</width>
          <height>32</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Показать</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="page_7">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_5">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>490</x>
          <y>40</y>
          <width>511</width>
          <height>41</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>В этой таблице находится статистика по самым сложным для Вас заданиям</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QComboBox" name="comboBox_2">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>30</x>
          <y>110</y>
          <width>221</width>
          <height>31</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QTableWidget" name="tableWidget_2">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>320</x>
          <y>110</y>
          <width>831</width>
          <height>551</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="show_2">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>80</x>
          <y>160</y>
          <width>113</width>
          <height>32</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Показать</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="page_8">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_3">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>410</x>
          <y>60</y>
          <width>601</width>
          <height>71</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Вы можете оставить комментарий, который прочитают и учтут разработчики, здесь:</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>760</x>
          <y>440</y>
          <width>113</width>
          <height>32</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Отправить</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QPlainTextEdit" name="plainTextEdit">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>420</x>
          <y>160</y>
          <width>521</width>
          <height>271</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </widget>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

subjects.txt

```
1;москва
2;санкт-петербург
3;севастополь
4;адыгея
5;алтай
6;башкортостан
7;бурятия
8;дагестан
9;ингушетия
10;кабардино-балкария
11;калмыкия
12;карачаево-черкессия
13;карелия
14;коми
15;крым
16;марий эл
17;мордовия
18;якутия
19;северная осетия
20;татарстан
21;тыва
22;удмуртия
23;хакасия
24;чечня
25:чувашия
26;ненецкий автономный округ
```

Comment: Please avoid using external resources to provide code, especially if they are code repositories which might change over time or become unaccessible, making your question invalid. Instead, [edit] your post and provide a [mre]. Besides that, consider that you should *not* use while loops or blocking functions, as they prevent proper processing of events in the UI loop (so, the UI is frozen, and no user interaction is possible). If you need to do something at specific intervals, use QTimer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I tried to make a minimal reproducible example, but since I do not know exactly where my mistake is, it turned out to reduce the code by only 300 lines. You say to make a QTimer interval instead of a while loop, but to be honest, I don't understand how to do this, because my while loop is just waiting for the timer to expire

Comment: I think the `while not ask:  pass` inside of the main while loop is blocking. I don't see where `ask` variable ever gets set to True.

Comment: You're probably right, but ask becomes true in the ready method, which is connected to the end of the timer in the idk method and to the send method when the response passes the check for correctness. 

But perhaps all this does not work, because ready is inside the game method, and there is no access to it from "outside", from other methods. But I also tried to take ready outside of the game method, but the program still didn't work

Comment: @cheronika you need to change the concept from procedural (loop until the time is out) to event driven (do something when the timer object emits its timeout signal). That's the whole concept beyond signals and slots.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't really understand how to do this, because if my timer sends some kind of signal, but you still need to check all the time that the signal has not been sent yet, and this will again lead me to the while loop

Comment: Or am I missing something fundamental?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).